# JQuery / dirty forms / window.onbeforeunload only triggered after link selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to implement a warning for the users in case they are leaving the form without saving.

The warning dialog works as expected but with the only exception that when the user chooses to 'Stay on Page', the *selected* side menu entry changed to the one the user clicked on (form is the same).

**How can I make sure that the same menu item is still selected once the user chooses to 'Stay on Page'?**

```
var warnMessage = "Unsaved changes. Do you really want to leave the page?";
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('a.k-link').on('click', function () {
      window.onbeforeunload = function () {
          if (isDirty) return warnMessage;
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: The class you're selecting on makes me think this is a Kendo/Telerik menu. Is that correct?

Comment: can you post a fiddle?

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @user797717 Which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following worked for me (adding e.stopPropagation):

```
  $('a.k-link').on('click', function (e) {
      if (isDirty && !confirm(warnMessage)) {     
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
      } });
```

or by returning false:

```
  $('a.k-link').on('click', function (e) {
      if (isDirty && !confirm(warnMessage)) {     
          return false;
      } });
```

Comment: Don't forget that you can accept your own answer; while accepting an answer is not required, it's a quick visual indicator that your problem has a satisfactory solution. You'll also earn a few more points.

Answer (score 1):

You might find it easier (and possibly more consistent across browsers) to use a confirm prompt (remember, it's a blocking dialog).

```
<script>
    var warnMessage = "Unsaved changes. Do you really want to leave the page?";

   $('a.k-link').on('click', function (e) {
        if (isDirty && !confirm(warnMessage)) {     
            e.preventDefault();         
        }
    });
</script>
```

There are at least two reasons to avoid `onbeforeunload`:

- The spec doesn't require a browser to display the message you
  provide, and [not all browsers do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload#syntax), and
- the correct event is actually [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload)

> You can and should handle this event through window.addEventListener() and the beforeunload  event. More documentation is available there. [(MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.onbeforeunload)

I'm just guessing, since the Kendo UI scripts aren't exactly fun to read through, but the 'selected' class is getting applied because a navigation event was *started*, even though you cancel it; the Kendo script is probably just listening for a successful click. `onbeforeunload` and `beforeunload` both happen after the click event has resolved (AFAIK, anyway).

Comment: Thanks! The code above does basically the same (selected class still applied) but your explanation helped me to find the solution to my problem. The methods stopPropagation & preventDefault together or just return false did the trick.